In Android How to store string and fetch it after reinstall application
I am making application and stuck at one point
How to store 1 string value and fetch it even after reinstall application.
Right now with sharedPreferences it is deleting all string data once i uninstall app,
is there any another way to keep string value in device even after app uninstall

Hello i have found one way to store text file externally, but once i reinstall the app, app can not read that text file again and it shows error of eacces permission denied.
code is as below.
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +"/Download/cl.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            // read text file content
            File filename;
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            new File(path + "/Download").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/Download/cl.txt");
            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(filename);

            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(fIn));
            String aDataRow = "";
            StringBuilder aBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                aBuffer.append(aDataRow).append("\n");
            }
            appInstallDate = String.valueOf(aBuffer);
            myReader.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " file exist " + appInstallDate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } else {
        try {
            // write text file content
            File filename;
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            new File(path + "/Download").mkdirs();
            filename = new File(path + "/Download/cl.txt");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            String firstDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " file write " + firstDate1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myOutWriter.append(firstDate1);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

